# Excel: Conditional Formatting - Two rules for one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I currently have conditional formatting set up to highlight a cell (E3) red when a payment is made after the due date. However, I have a "late fee paid" column. I want to add a rule where if there is a date (m/d/yy) in the late fee paid cell (F3) that cell E3 turns green.

I've tried a variety of rules and can't seem to get E3 to call to F3 to get the formatting.

[Current formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13hhz.png)

[Conditional formatting I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvoms.png)

My current rule for the green fill is

```
=COUNTIF($F3,"")>0
```

which is highlighting the cells in E3 as green if there is no text in F3. I am trying to make it where E3 is green if the text in F3 is a date. I've tried putting "D4" and m/d/yy and neither is working so this rule isn't correct.

Comment: Show your broken rules.

Comment: Conditional formatting is order dependent.  Create two rules.  Change order as required.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I am aware, the issue is that I'm not getting the green fill rule to work regardless of the order.

Comment: @r2d3 Added in an edit

Comment: Use Not(IsBlank(F3))

Comment: mk-kassandra, I gave you another hint. Show me your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is highlighting the cells in E3 as green if there is no text in F3. I am trying to make it where E3 is green if the text in F3 is a date. I've tried putting "D4" and m/d/yy and neither is working so this rule isn't correct.

Do not try to evaluate the color of a cell which is coloured by a conditional formating as trigger for another conditional formating.

Furthermore, contrary to your own rules described in words, "D4" does not effect the formating of D3 and E3. I don't understand why you did this.

As you only have one settings of format per rule but you require two colours you either paint your sheet in green and have your negative deviations painted in red. That requires just one rule.

If your background is to be white you would need two rules, one for the red and one for the green color.

Although you can place complicated rules into the conditional formatting formula line, I recommend you doing something different because it simplifies fast modifications of formulas.

Use a helper column "G"  for the formula.
Then link the conditional formating to the helper column by writing the conditional formating in D3 as
IF(G3=TRUE) 'red color conditional formating

Put in either TRUE and FALSE in G3 to see that it works.
Now put your conditional formating formula in G3.
That is faster to manipulate and easier to work with than the conditional formating  editor.

When handling dates for your purposes you only need the "<" or ">" operator.
An empty cell while be evaluted as having a value of 0.

In words the formula for your red painting in D3 is:

If a payment is overdue and the late fee is not paid, paint cell in red.

There is the And() operator for this.

Please don't mind me not stating the complete solution, I want to teach you helping yourself.

show your new solution!

## added 8.8.2021 18:26 MEZ:

red color rule:

If a payment is overdue and the late fee is not paid, paint cell in red.=>

=AND("If a payment is overdue";"late fee is not paid")

Red color rule applies when both criteria apply!

Now it's your turn, turn the phrases into formula conditions!

Comment: I misunderstood D4, I believe it is a date code and I thought I would try to get the formula to read IF F3 has D4 (m/d/yy), make E3 green, but that obviously was the wrong way to go about it. I am trying to use the AND operator but I'm consistently failing, I think this is just above me at this point.

Comment: Here are the solutions I have so far: Using @StainlessSteelRat 's suggestion of doing Not(IsBlank(F3)), which works except I kind of wanted it to recognize dates in the F column only, not any text. Same goes for the COUNTIF formula in my original answer - I may go with that and make the select word "paid." Final solution is doing =CELL("format",$F3)="D4" - my issue is that if I type a date in, then hit delete, the formatting of the cell is still in "D4" so the E3 cell remains green despite no text being in F3.